# u32 filter matching clarification

Tags: iptables

I've been following through the tutorial for u32 pattern matching here: [Link](http://www.stearns.org/doc/iptables-u32.current.html)

Most of it is straightforward until I get to the section where the IP header length is grabbed, using the following:

```
0>>22&0x3C
```

I don't understand why this was chosen instead of:

```
0>>24&0x0F
```

From my understanding, the filter chosen will shift the first byte 22 to the right, then apply a mask to strip the first and last 2 bits off, giving us to the correct lower nibble for the IP header length. The second will complete the full shift to the right, only needing to strip the first 4 bits.

My question is, why was the first chosen and not the second? I believe it's because of the multiply that needs to take place, but I don't understand what effect that operation would have if both filters would return the correct value.

Answer (score 1):

The IP Header length is specified in 32 bit words rather than 8 bit bytes, so whatever value is in the IPH field will need to be multiplied by 4 which can be accomplished by a shift left of 2; therefore instead of shifting right by 24, masking by 0x0F and shifting right by two the author decided only to shift right by 22 and masking by 0x03c.

That is, both operations don't return the same value, the first operation returns the value of the second multiplied by 4. To get the same result as the first you would

```
0>>24&0x0F<<2
```